# Limit replicas per node on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to limit the number os replicas per node in Kubernetes? I found some info about Spreading Constraints but didn't understand if this is possible.

Example: I want to have only 1 replica per node on the cluster.

I know that K8S automatically balances the replicas spreading across the nodes, but I want to enforce a specific limit in each node.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure that all nodes have single replica on them you can use a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/).

Comment: I think this simple solution fits. I'm running a meet server in containers, and it can only runs one server per machine, so I'll configure Node auto-scaling in a cloud K8S cluster instead of pod autoscaling, but for this I need this 'one replica per node' behavior. Thank you!

Comment: In case if I wanted to run N pods per node, how is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

The scheduler has many ways to just about everything but in the particular case of 1 replica per node you can use a `required` mode anti-affinity.

Answer (score 1):

You can create daemon set which makes sure every node in the cluster runs exactly one replica